# Custom registration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have changed the default unsigned integer `id` of `User` table to uuid or char(36). For it to automatically generate Uuid during saving of new user, I have changed the  `register` function in  `RegistersUsers` trait to as -

```
 public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    $inputsArray=$request->all();

    $inputsArray['id']=(string)Uuid::generate();
    //dd($inputsArray);
    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($inputsArray));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Finally, it saves the new user data but with blank `id` column. I thought the uuid is not generated but when I dumped $inputsArray there was `id` value with 36 chars. Help me understand this, to save the data with user id. Thanks.

Comment: How are you defining the id field in your migration? Actually creating your user table with the $table->uuid('id') field should do the trick

Comment: @Andrew I got it already by your method, but the stated method not working don't know why.